# during vs in and grammar uses

Tags: grammar

Hello  why during June \ December is not possible according to this page ?

Q 3. San Francisco is often foggy and overcast  in June, but not in  December.

Here in this page which its link below the suggested answer should be only in suggesting using ( in ) for specific time and during when there is duration. I agree with idea, but why it is not possible to use ( during May or June ). On the other hand it is possible to use both ( in, during ) the summer \ during the winter etc... The page is starting by this introduction:

**left side:**

During is rarely used to differentiate when an activity happened. (It occurred X time not Y time.) However, during can be used to differentiate a range of time, for example, a decade or century written as 1920s or 1900s.

**Right side:**

In can be used to differentiate when an activity happened. (It occurred X time not Y time.) Use with periods of the day or a specific month, year, century, or era. https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/preps_during-in.html

Comment: I don't think during would be wrong in your example, but "in" is a lot less to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use either, but you probably never mean “during June / December” when referring to very specific weather, so you probably should not use *during*.

For example, these having different meanings:

1. > San Francisco is often foggy and overcast in June, but not in December.
2. > San Francisco is often foggy and overcast during June, but not during December.

(1) means that in San Francisco, every year, there are many days in June that are foggy and overcast. (2) means that in San Francisco, there are many years that it is foggy and overcast for the entire month of June.

The meaning of (2) is not impossible, but it is rarely what we want to say, because it is rarely accurate. Therefore you can say it, but rarely will you want to.

Meanwhile, saying it is cold during winter is often accurate, as is saying that it is cold in winter, so both are commonly used.

Similarly, you can say that you stayed at a friend’s house during June, or you can say you stayed in June: the different words suggest different lengths of stay, but both suggest something reasonable.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Thank you very much